# Using curve() to generate predicted counts

Tags: r, plot, curve

## Goal

I would like to use the `plot()` and `curve()` functions to generate a plot of predicted counts. I have run a count model with a relatively small dataset.

## Question

What code can I use to generate predicted counts?

## Data

My **dependent variable** is a count of the number of petitions received by a government bureau.

My **independent variable** is a continuous variable ranging from 0 to 3.

My regression result is `all.glm`

I have used the following code to attempt this:

```
# Extract Coefficients and Alpha
all.alpha <- coef(all.glm)[1]
all.coeff <- coef(all.glm)[2]

# Generate synthetic values
varx <- seq(0, 3, 0.25)

# Generate Plot
plot(-10, -10,)

# Add curves
for (i in 1:length(corrx)) {
  curve(pnorm(all.alpha*1 + all.coeff*varx[i,]), add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
  }
```

As you can see, I created a vector of fake independent variable values, and I am attempting to iterate through them to generate a variety of predicted results.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Error in curve((all.alpha * 1 + all.coef * 1.5), add = TUE, lwd = 2) :
'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

I'm sure this is a dumb error, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `predict(all.glm)` will give you predictions for the data values used to fit the model. To generate predictions for new data, do `predict(all.glm, newdata=new.data)` where `new.data` is a data frame with values of the independent variables you want to use for predictions.

Comment: Thank you, @eipi10 ! I had no idea that this existed (R newbie).

Comment: Pretty much every modeling function has a `predict` "method". That is, for whatever model you run (`lm`, `glm`, `randomForest`, whatever) doing `predict(model_object)` will return predictions appropriate to that model type.

Comment: FYI, `curve` expects a function of one variable, but your function has two variables (`all.alpha` and `all.coeff`). In addition, if you're using a function you create (as opposed to a built-in function), then the argument has to be called `x`. Do `?curve` and scroll down the help for examples.

Comment: Agree w/ @eipi10, but would add that if you want tested solutions, then you would need to provide either simulation code that produces a model equivalent to yours in terms of complexity or provide the output of `dput(all.glm)`

Comment: Guys - you're all awesome. Thank you so much for your input!